# How do I compare single array of objects with it key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have an array of objects, Where I need to compare "taskId" & "resourceId" of its own array of objects and push the result in a new array.
Here is my array

```
data = [{
  "resourceId":1234
  "taskId":5001
  "taskName":"Test task1"
 },
 {
  "resourceId":1234
  "taskId":5001
  "taskName":"Test task2"
}
{
 "resourceId":1234
 "taskId":5002
 "taskName":"Test task3"
},
{
 "resourceId":1234
 "taskId":5001
 "taskName":"Test task4"
},
{
 "resourceId":5678
 "taskId":5003
 "taskName":"Test task5"
},
{
 "resourceId":5678
 "taskId":5004
 "taskName":"Test task6"
}
]
```

Please help me to build this logic. I appreciate your efforts in advance.

Comment: What kind of comparison do you want to do? Otherwise all we can do is guesswork

Comment: need result example

Comment: Need a new array of object with the result of where "taskId" & "resourceId" is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```
var result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
    var value = a.resourceId.toString().concat(a.taskId);
    r[value] = r[value] || [];
    r[value].push(a);
    return r;
}, Object.create(null));
```

This will result the new array as shown below, you can modify the key name(array names) as required

[image]

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2cpe3ts6/

Comment: Thanks for your replay, But can't we push the result into two simple arrays(one array with matched and another without matched), Bcz it's too confusing me to use.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new method `filterArray` to filter the array.

```
function filterArray(dataArray, resourceId, taskId){
   return dataArray.filter(item => item.resourceId === resourceId && item.taskId === taskId)
}
```

The `filter` method on the array will loop through each item in the `dataArray`, compare the values of `resourceId` and `taskId` and if they matches, push them to the new array. This new array is returned from the method.

You can now call this method to filter:

```
let filteredArray = filterArray(data, 1234, 5001)
```

`filteredArray` will now contain all items with `resourceId = 1234` and `taskId = 5001`

Comment: The requirement is to filter all the objects with same taskid and resource id.. not object where taskid and resourceid are equal.

Comment: @SasiKumarM I have now corrected. The requirement was not clear in the beginning. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

1- Your JSON array isn't well formatted.

2- As per your expected outcome in comments, basically you need those data which have multiple occurrences only. So here is how you can get:

```js
var data = [{
      "resourceId":1234,
      "taskId":5001,
      "taskName":"Test task1"
     },
     {
      "resourceId":1234,
      "taskId":5001,
      "taskName":"Test task2"
    },
    {
     "resourceId":1234,
     "taskId":5002,
     "taskName":"Test task3"
    },
    {
     "resourceId":1234,
     "taskId":5001,
     "taskName":"Test task4"
    },
    {
     "resourceId":5678,
     "taskId":5003,
     "taskName":"Test task5"
    },
    {
     "resourceId":5678,
     "taskId":5004,
     "taskName":"Test task6"
    }
    ];

    const result = [];
    data.forEach((item) => { 
        let dupes = data.filter((elem) => elem.resourceId == item.resourceId && elem.taskId == item.taskId);
        if (dupes.length >1) {
            result.push(item);
        }
    });

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Static values bad idea

Comment: Just for demo, he may use dynamic values

Comment: I need all objects where "taskId & resourceId" is same.

Comment: Could you post an expected outcome with the current data you provided ? Do you mean taskId == resourceId or do you want duplicates ?

Comment: Expected array (taskId == resourceId) 
newArray = [
 {
   "resourceId":1234,
   "taskId":5001,
   "taskName":"Test task1"
  },
  {
   "resourceId":1234,
   "taskId":5001,
   "taskName":"Test task2"
 },
 {
  "resourceId":1234,
  "taskId":5001,
  "taskName":"Test task4"
 }
]

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = [{
  "resourceId":1234,
  "taskId":5001,
  "taskName":"Test task1"
 },
 {
  "resourceId":1234,
  "taskId":5001,
  "taskName":"Test task2"
},
{
 "resourceId":1234,
 "taskId":5002,
 "taskName":"Test task3"
},
{
 "resourceId":1234,
 "taskId":5001,
 "taskName":"Test task4"
},
{
 "resourceId":5678,
 "taskId":5003,
 "taskName":"Test task5"
},
{
 "resourceId":5678,
 "taskId":5004,
 "taskName":"Test task6"
}
]
var result=[];
data.map(x=>{
 var i=result.findIndex(y=> y.resourceId==x.resourceId && y.taskId==x.taskId );
 if( i == -1){
  result.push( { "resourceId":x.resourceId,"taskId":x.taskId,"taskName":x.taskName } )
 }else{
  result[i].taskName += " "+x.taskName;
 }
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: It is pushing the 1st object also. In my case, it should not push the first object.

Comment: check my other answer please it may help you

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = [{
  "resourceId":1234,
  "taskId":5001,
  "taskName":"Test task1"
 },
 {
  "resourceId":1234,
  "taskId":5001,
  "taskName":"Test task2"
},
{
 "resourceId":1234,
 "taskId":5002,
 "taskName":"Test task3"
},
{
 "resourceId":1234,
 "taskId":5001,
 "taskName":"Test task4"
},
{
 "resourceId":5678,
 "taskId":5003,
 "taskName":"Test task5"
},
{
 "resourceId":5678,
 "taskId":5004,
 "taskName":"Test task6"
}
]
var result=[];
data.map(x=>{
 var i=result.findIndex(y=> y.resourceId==x.resourceId && y.taskId==x.taskId );
 if( i == -1){
  result.push( { "resourceId":x.resourceId,"taskId":x.taskId,"taskName":[x.taskName] } )
  
 }else{
  result[i].taskName.push( x.taskName);
 }
})
console.log(result)
```